# Java JDK Libraries are already pre-compiled?

Tags: java

Are Java JDK libraries already pre-compiled? or it compiles with our code that are using these libraries

Answer (score 1):

The official JDK distributions are pre-compiled. You could always download the source and build it yourself, though.